# How to added the two version of layer to lambda one layer support only 3.8 and other one layer 3.7 version layer in python?

Tags: python, pandas, google-ads-api

I need to import `pandas` and google ads in the AWS lambda function. `pandas` support only the 3.7 version and google ads support only the 3.8 version.

When I've given lambda 3.8 version google ads works and `pandas` get an error and when I'm given lambda 3.7 version `pandas` works and google ads get an error.

Please guide me on how to support the two versions of layers.

Comment: Current pandas version supports 3.8. What's the problem with using the pandas version compatible with 3.8?

Comment: Actually, 3.8 is currently the *lowest* supported version (3.8-3.10 currently supported). So you using pandas that works on 3.7 and not 3.8 means that you use some ooold version.

Comment: when I'm using pandas 3.8 version getting this error Unable to import module 'lambda_function': Unable to import required dependencies:\nnumpy: \n\nIMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!\n\nImporting the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for\nmany reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was\ninstalled.\n\nWe have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:\n\n    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html\n\

Comment: No, you're not using "pandas 3.8 version" because pandas version numbers don't go like python versions. You just mean you tried to run the version you currently have with python3.8. Which is not how you do that because pandas contains C extensions (as the error told you). You have to actually use python3.8's pip to install that to your lambda location.